# How do I delete my Skype billing agreement on PayPal?

Tags: paypal, skype-for-web

How do I delete my Skype billing agreement on PayPal?

I wanted to delete the PayPal payment method from my Skype account, but I've been told to delete the agreement on PayPal.

However, I can't find such option on the PayPal website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out how. I went to see my payments history on the PayPal website, and clicked on the Skype row. You'll see the option to delete the Skype deal.

Answer (score 13):

Log on PayPal → My Profile → My Money → My pre-approved payments → Update → Select Skype on Merchant List → Cancel.

Comment: -1 when you log on to PayPal there is no [any longer] "My Profile" option

Comment: This answer is no longer valid

Answer (score 3):

I believe one place that can be found is under Profile -> More Options -> My Preapproved Payments -> Update. There may be places too.

Clear as mud, eh?

Comment: FWIW, I didn't know these things even existed until Skype surprised me by taking money out of my PayPal. Skype also starts the automatic billing unless you opt out every time you add money, even if you already cancelled the "agreement" once, so be careful.

Answer (score 1):

Just did this and I am sure it has changed. Go to the individual transaction in Activity, click on Transaction Details. From there click on View Billing Agreement. There you will find the Cancel option.

Comment: It has changed. Paypal does their best to make canceling subscriptions to Skype impossible.

Answer (score 1):

### 03-23-2020 Paypal Version

[Direct Link](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_manage-paylist)

Menu Cog Icon -> Account Settings -> Website Payments -> My Automatic Payments -> My preapproved payments

### Notes:

- "Website Payments" is under "Products and Services" on the Account Settings screen
- "My preapproved payments" is a hyperlink on the "Website Payments" screen, rather than a menu option. You'll have to look closely for it.

## PayPal intentionally makes this difficult. Cancel your Paypal account.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated answer based on the new platform.

Click on My Account and then History submenu. On the top of the list locate More Filters, go down to Subscriptions and Agreements and then you'll have Billing Agreements.

For some reason it doesn't show my Skype one but I basically just agreed to it so maybe that's why.

Comment: Not any more.  There is no My Account.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions (Re: History, More filters - Subscriptions and agreements) worked well with the new Skype layout. All that was left in order to find Skype Billing Agreements was to change the search dates to further back. Then I went into Skype and to view the agreement and cancelled it. Hope it works. Will see once my balance goes under $10.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal.com > Cog (Settings) > My Pre-approved payments > Skype > Cancel

Comment: Not any more.  I am still looking...

Answer (score 0):

Click Cog Icon on top right -> Payments Tab -> Manage Automatic Payments in middle top -> Active and Inactive subscriptions show on left.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to paypal.com
2. Select the payment you want to cancel
3. Click *Detail*
4. Click *View Billing Agreement Details*
5. Click *Cancel*

Comment: Aint no such detail to click any more.